# Azure Functions .NET 5.0 Issue with Triggers

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

Based on these two sites I created an Azure Function for .NET 5.0:

[(Preview) Creating Azure Functions using .NET 5](https://codetraveler.io/2021/02/12/creating-azure-functions-using-net-5/)

[Use Azure Functions with .NET 5](https://daveabrock.com/2021/02/24/functions-dotnet-5)

Everything compiles, but when I publish it detects the following:

```
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading 16.64 MB
Upload completed successfully.
Deployment completed successfully.
Syncing triggers...
Functions in AppDev:
     OrderSubmitterFunction - [No Trigger Found]
     OtherSubmitterFunction - [No Trigger Found]
```

In one of my function classes:

```
[Function(nameof(OrderSubmitterFunction))]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("orders", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
```

and another:

```
[Function(nameof(OtherSubmitterFunction))]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger(containerName + "/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
```

I suspect the above is the issue as these trigger attributes do not seem to get picked up. The functions do however get noticed.

For reference my start up class is:

```
static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
        })
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddDbContext<Context>(opts =>
            {
                var conn = config.GetConnectionString("Context");
                opts.UseSqlServer(conn);
            });
        })
        .Build();

    return host.RunAsync();
}
```

Does anyone notice anything with the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and you can find it in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/178#issuecomment-796313124). I have the same issue during publish:

[image]

Since the function can work without any impacts, we can ignore it at this time.

By the way, we should follow [the official doc 1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker#create-and-run-net-isolated-functions) or [official doc 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-developer-howtos?tabs=browser&pivots=development-environment-vs)  to create Azure Function for .NET 5.0.